# How to use Logical indexing and min function to find the row which has min value?

Tags: r

So, I know how to find it using the subset function. Is there any way not to use subset function?

Example dataset:

```
Month A B  
J 67 89  
F 48 69  
M 78 89 
A 54 90 
M 54 75
```

So, lets say I need to write a code to find the **min** value in **Column B**.

My Code: `subset(df, B == min(df)`

My question:
How to use Logical indexing and min function for this dataset?  I don't wanna use subset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` to find the postitions.

```
x <- c(2,1,3,1)
which(x == min(x))
#[1] 2 4
```

To get the first hit `which.min` could be used.

```
which.min(x)
#[1] 2
```

With the given data set.

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Month A B
J 67 89
F 48 69
M 78 89
A 54 90
M 54 75")

which(x$B == min(x$B))
#[1] 2

which(x[2:3] == min(x[2:3]), TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   2   1
```

Comment: What about the column?

Comment: Can you give an example dataset and also what you have done already using `subset` and show an expected result?

Comment: please check the above

Comment: sorry the dataset looks ugly, but this can let you know example. lets say we have a data frame.